# The file is not being printed out,what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, io

I have been trying to get the output of this code to be printed on a .txt file, however I getting an empty file as an output, but I see the correct results in the console, so the problem is with the StreamWriter I think.

So what am I doing wrong?

```
package Hierarchies;

    public static void generateHierarchy() {

        Set<Entry<Long, Node>> iterator = graph.entrySet();
        int i =0;
        for(Entry<Long,Node> e : iterator) {
            System.out.println(i++ +" - " +e.getValue().firstParents());
        }

    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "resource" })
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JWNLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        dictionary = Dictionary.getDefaultResourceInstance();

        File dir = new File("C:/Users/D060891/Desktop/Thesis/sentencesNYT");

        for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {

            try {
                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                String line;

                while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                    demonstrateListHelper(line);                              
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        generateHierarchy();
        PrintStream out;
        try {
            out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("output.txt"));
            System.setOut(out);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where's your file writer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a file and write to a file in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/how-to-create-a-file-and-write-to-a-file-in-java)

Comment: Possible reasons: 1) You don't flush or close the PrintSteam. 2) Your directory is empty and no file are read. 3) All the files in that directory are empty.

Comment: Can you please add the `demonstrateListHelper` method? Another reason: You don't `System.setOut` until after you looped over all the files.

Comment: I do not see you writting anything to the file. I just see how you create a PrintStream to a file and assign it to System.out, but then you do not print nothing. Call `generateHierarchy()` after you asign out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see you writting anything to the file. I just see how you create a PrintStream to a file and assign it to System.out, but then you do not print nothing. Call `generateHierarchy()` after you asign out

Comment: well that was a bit embarrassing, I see what's happening now ... I've only started to code 6 months ago and for some reason I keep doing such silly mistakes, thank you :)

Comment: @LuckyOwl We all have been there. Thats why stackoverflow exists ;)

Answer (score 0):

Flush and close the stream. It might be the case that program is ending before data is flushed into the disk. Note that higher level streams maintain a buffer and hence don't write directly to disk.

Answer (score -1):

You try to write the file by redirecting System.out, but redirect it only after the data has been written to System.out.

You should be doing something like:

```
void printHierarchy(PrintStream ps) {
    ...
    ps.println(...)
}
```

and in main():

```
try (PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("output.txt"))) {
    printHierarchy(ps);
}
```

Comment: That actually was the solution yes, I fixed it by the answer previously given, thank you.